# Ruby system method on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows

When I use the `system` method in Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows, nothing happens.

Here's a snippet:

```
system("ruby.exe \"some_file\" \"#{$0}\"")
```

Both some_file and $0 exist, so I don't see why it shouldn't work. Ruby.exe is never called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think ruby takes the program name in quotes.

Comment: Is `ruby.exe` available in your path? You might need to use the explicit path to the executable. Also, try `%Q[ruby.exe "some_file" "#{$0}"]` for a cleaner string definition.

Comment: @theTinMan nope, that doesn't work :|

Comment: @itdoesntwork: Is there any reason that you must call `ruby.exe` explicitly? Can't you just `eval` that, or put it in a separate thread? Or even `require "some_file"`?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh I have to pass a commandline argument to that file. I can't require it.

Comment: @itdoesntwork: `system` print to stdout. Should `some_file` print anything? Could you try to call it with backticks? Or try `p %x{ruby.exe "some_file" "#{$0}"}` If the result is `""` something happened, but there was no screen output.